# Inserting iterable containers into map for keys and values

Tags: c++

I have two arrays like the following. The arrays are always the same size.

```
std::array<int, 5> keys;
std::array<int, 5> values;
```

I want to load them into a map for the keys and values, respectively.

```
std::unordered_map<int, int> map;

for (int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++) {
     map.emplace(keys[i], values[i]);
}
```

Is there no built-in insert method or function for inserting pairs like the following?

```
map.insert(keys.begin(), keys.end(), values.begin(), values.end());
map.insert(keys, values);
```

Thanks

Note: Normally, I would be fine with iterating over the arrays to build the map but I have to do this several times.

Comment: I don't think `std::map` has such a method. But why not write a utility function for that (this will surely tidy up your code) ?

Comment: I could. I was asking if there was an obscure built in method or function.

Comment: There is no built-in function to merge two related containers into a single `map` for you, no. But it would be fairly trivial to write such a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve the goal using STL `std::transform` with the help of `std::inserter`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::array<int, 5> keys{1,2,3,4,5};
    std::array<int, 5> values{10,20,30,40,50}; 
    
    std::unordered_map<int, int> map;

    transform(keys.begin(), keys.end(), values.begin(), inserter(map, map.end()), [](const int &a, const int &b) {return make_pair(a, b);}); 
    
    for (const auto &[key, val] : map) {
        cout << key << ":" << val << endl;
    } 
}
```

Output:

```
5:50
4:40
3:30
1:10
2:20
```

Comment: I'll accept this as the solution since there doesn't seem to be another c++ style solution. However, I think I prefer c style over this.